# Height of a Rose Tree Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, numbers, height

Consider the following definition of Rose Trees:

```
data RTree a = R a [RTree a]
```

I need help defining the function `rtHeight :: (RTree a) -> Int` that calculates the height of a rose tree.

So far, I have tried the following

```
rtHeight R a [] = 1
rtHeight R a l = 1 + rtHeight l
```

However, this does not work becuase l is a list of rose trees.
I have also tried the following:

```
rtHeight R a [] = 1
rtHeight R a l = maximum (map (rtHeight) l)
```

I believe this fails becuase I am not adding a level while I am going down the tree.

Comment: You're so close! Just mix and match: take the bit from the one solution that adds a level, and the bit from the other solution that handles lists. (And don't forget to correct your parentheses.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my final answer. Tested and it worked:

```
rtHeight R a [] = 1
rtHeight R a l = 1 + maximum (map (rtHeight) l)
```

Answer (score 3):

In [Why Functional Programming Matters](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Erjmh/Papers/whyfp.html) [(PDF)](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf), the author includes a code that is equivalent to the following:

```
reduce_tree f g z t =
  f (label t) (reduce (g . reduce_tree f g z) z (branches t))
```

Using it, we can write

```
rtHeight t = reduce_tree f g z t
  where
    f _ y  = 1 + y      -- 1 more than maximum height of subtrees
    g x y  = max x y    -- y is maximum height of subtrees to the right
    z      = 0          -- the smallest height is 0

label    (R a _ ) = a
branches (R _ bs) = bs
reduce = foldr
```

As an illustration, for a tree `t = R a [b,c,d]`, this calculates `t`'s height as

```
rtHeight t = 1 + max (rtHeight b)         -- rtHeight == reduce_tree f g z
                     (max (rtHeight c)
                          (max (rtHeight d)
                               0))
```

That is because, for the built-in [`foldr` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr),

```
foldr g z [a,b,c,...,n] == g a (g b (g c (... (g n z)...)))
```

An interesting identity is `foldr (g . h) z xs == foldr g z (map h xs)`, and since `maximum (xs ++ [0]) == foldr max 0 xs`, your direct recursive formulation of `rtHeight` can be recovered from this generalized formulation.